# CodeIgniter 'MY_' can not be found in ... error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-state

I have been working on a session validation for my login to make sure that a user is logged in to view pages. I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Staffcontroller' not found in /usr/local/var/www/CodeTest
>   /ci/application/controllers/staff_c.php on line 3

My `staff_c` page looks like so :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Staff_c extends MY_Staffcontroller {

    function homepage()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'homepage_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }
}
```

I have been reading same questions all over the place and they say the same thing pretty much...

> *Is your controller located in application/core?*

Well yes it is. I can't seem to get passed this hump!

[image: Controller image]

This is the code within `My_Staffcontroller.php`:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_staffcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $loggedin = $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
        if(!isset($loggedin) || $loggedin != TRUE);
        {
            die($this->load->view('denied'));
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is user error as this is only my second day with CodeIgniter but I can't seem to find proper workaround for this?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678798/codeigniter-check-for-user-session-in-every-controller) tutorial and still nothing and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026170/codeigniter-sessions-checking-from-a-header-view-file)

Even following [this video](http://blip.tv/nettuts/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-6-2973653) has me stuck on the session part.

And I just can not get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remember** Linux is *case-sensative* whereas Windows is case-insensative.

place you're `MY_Staffcontroller` inside `application/core/MY_Controller.php` file

Your `MY_Controller.php` file should look like this (minus all you're other functions, this is a minimal example)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   public function __construct() 
   {
       parent::__construct(); 
   }
}
class MY_Staffcontroller extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }
    public function sayHello()
    { 
        echo "Hello, I am a function within MY_Staffcontroller.php";
    }
}
```

**Example**

This will be located in `/application/controllers` directory
Basically any `protected` and `public` functions located in either `MY_Controller` OR `MY_Staffcontroller` will be accessible from derived controllers that extend the extended controller. In this case it would be `MY_Staffcontroller`

```
class Public_Staff_Controller extends MY_Staffcontroller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->sayHello();
    }
}

/* end of file /application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

Comment: alright, I didn't get any errors this time (for once) I however didn't get anything period (just a blank page). I feel it is because of my die($this->load->view('invalid));

Comment: I just edited my answer. Check it out. It is a simple example that will help you grasp the concept of this pattern. This is the best way to use CodeIgniter IMO

Comment: I'm still working on this. Don't think I am not reading your edits. Your awesome, thank you.

Comment: @RaGe10940 Not a problem. It's why I'm here.

Comment: Oh sorry for commenting late, this worked perfectly. I am using this system as my user authorization and role authorization. Thanks a lot!