# When session starts header file changes after refreshing the page

Tags: php, codeigniter

New to Codeigniter.

This is my header file. After getting logged in, the header file needs to be changed but it changes after I refresh the page. Same is when I logout. Kindly help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/home')?>>HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/about')?>>ABOUT</a> </li>
        <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/contact')?>>CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION["name"])){
      ?>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/welcome')?>><?php echo $_SESSION["name"];?></a></li>
          <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/logout')?>>Logout<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
                        }else{
        ?>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/register')?>>REGISTER<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href=<?php echo base_url( 'form/login')?>>LOGIN<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> </a></li>
          </ul>
          <?php
                        }
          ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: header file needs to be changed ? can you elaborate this?

Comment: are you using ajax for login?

Comment: do a refresh/redirect with php on login and logout. im guessing the logic which controls the `$_SESSION` vars is done after this header is outputted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Sessions Checking from a header view file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026170/codeigniter-sessions-checking-from-a-header-view-file)

Comment: Please check have you load session library in controller...

Comment: @webpic thats what I am asking, is there any need to change header file or need to add something in MVC?

Comment: @BilalAhmed No, not using ajax.

Comment: show the controller how you define the session?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Please tell what exactly I have to write. I tried redirect("welcome", refresh); Welcome is the view file after Login gets validated, but instead it showed codeigniter's welcome page

Comment: In Your Controller ... $this->load->library('session');  and check it .. like this..
print_r($this->session->all_user_data());

Comment: @Shihas loaded session library. Sessions works well, problem is that after login, header needs to be changed.

Comment: @Alisha you must be setting/resetting the session variables after loading the header file, put your session related code before you load the header view...

Comment: What is the session name you have given?

Comment: @Alisha  .. Can I know which code is you used to redirect .. ?

Comment: @Shihas if($query -> num_rows() == 1) { 
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array('name' => $row->name);
            $name = $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true; //this is how I held the name of user
        }

Comment: hmm.. can you show me welcome .. funtion you called ..

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition inorder to create session with a name.

```
if($query -> num_rows() == 1) 
{ 
  $row = $query->row(); 
  $data = array('name' => $row->name); 
  $this->session->set_userdata('loggin_session',$data); // given a name to session(i.e loggin_session). 
  return true;
}
```

Now in your View change like following:

```
<?php 
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('loggin_session');
     if(isset($session_data['name'])){ 
?> 
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                  
            <li><a href=<?php echo  base_url('form/welcome')?>><?php echo $_SESSION["name"];?></a></li>
            <li><a href=<?php echo  base_url('form/logout')?>>Logout<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
     </ul>
<?php }else{ ?> 
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href=<?php echo  base_url('form/register')?>>REGISTER<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
           <li><a href=<?php echo  base_url('form/login')?>>LOGIN<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> </a></li>
     </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No, Its not. Thanks anyways. I did it just by redirecting.

Comment: remove `isset` and try